# Wordpress intercepting response Location header impossible, response headers are always null and empty

Tags: wordpress, http, null, header

I am developing a plugin for a wordpress website which interacts with a third party HTTP API.

For one specific request I am completely dependent on a response header. It's a `Location` header used for redirection, from which I need to get the url and query parameters.

The request:

```
    return wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'body' => http_build_query(array(
            'token' => <omitted>,
            'email' => <omitted>,
            'password' => <omitted>
        )),
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
        'redirection' => 0
    ));
```

While testing the request above I noticed the `headers` response fields are `null` and `{}`:

```
{
   "headers": {},
   "body": "",
   "response": {
      "code": 303,
      "message": "See Other"
   },
   "cookies": [
      {
         "name": "JSESSIONID",
         "value": "<omitted>",
         "expires": null,
         "path": "/<omitted>",
         "domain": "test.<omitted>.com",
         "host_only": true
      }
   ],
   "filename": null,
   "http_response": {
      "data": null,
      "headers": null,
      "status": null
   }
}
```

The request is working fine in Postman, where all the expected response headers are clearly visible. I also turned off following redirections in Postman for this specific request to be able to intercept the Location header before the redirection occurs.

I have tried:

1. another wordpress instance: same issue, no headers
2. a local docker wordpress instance: same issue, no headers
3. a different http request (`GET https://example.com`): same issue, no headers
4. setting redirection to `1` instead of `0`: same issue, no headers, ***BUT*** the redirect actually works, which means the `Location` header is present and `wp_remote_post` picked it up - this makes it even harder to understand why I cannot see or retrieve any headers.

Here's the response when I GET https://example.com:

```
{
   "headers": {},
   "body": "<omitted>",
   "response": {
      "code": 200,
      "message": "OK"
   },
   "cookies":[],
   "filename": null,
   "http_response": {
      "data": null,
      "headers": null,
      "status": null
   }
}
```

I have been searching for hours and I haven't gotten a step closer to resolving this issue. Any assistance is most welcome.

edit: someone asked me for the cURL PHP code from Postman:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '<omitted>/auth/login',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'token=<omitted>&email=<omitted>&password=<omitted>',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie: JSESSIONID=<omitted>'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: What does the generated code for PHP cURL from postman look like?

Comment: @HowardE Added the PHP cURL snippet at the end of the post - it is a weird snippet since it is different from the actual Postman settings, e.g. the follow redirects is on for the generated cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by using another http library 'Requests'.
Wordpress usually includes this library by default.

```
$url = "$this->base_url/$this->base_path/auth/login";
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

$data = array(
    'token' => <omitted>,
    'email' => <omitted>,
    'password' => <omitted>
);

$options = array(
    'follow_redirects' => false
);

return Requests::post($url, $headers, $data, $options);
```

It does not solve the issue with wp_remote, but replaces it nicely for this specific request.